# What exactly is a Parzen?

Tags: terminology, definitions, probability

I came across the term "Parzen" while reading the research paper titled [Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf). It has been used in the research paper in two contexts.

**#1**: In phrase "Parzen window"

> We estimate probability of the test set data under $p_g$ by **fitting a
> Gaussian Parzen window** to the samples generated with $G$ and reporting
> the log-likelihood under this distribution.

**#2**: In phrase "Parzen density estimation"

> Evaluating $p(x)$ in Generative autoencoders and Adversarial models: Not
> explicitly represented, may be approximated with **Parzen density
> estimation**

Is there any definition for the word Parzen and how is it related to the probability distributions?

Answer (score 2):

[Parzen](https://statistics.stanford.edu/history/emanuel-parzen) was a statistician, who worked in spectral analysis and stochastic processes. I don't know if he invented them, but those windows and probability density esimation methods are named after him.

See also his [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Parzen).